# Truncate all tables (except desired ones) is not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a command in terminal which will truncate all tables in database except don't truncate those tables which are specified. This are my commands

```
// create tmp database
mysql -h localhost -u root -proot -e "create database testDb;"
// create tmp user and grant all PRIVILEGES for testDb
mysql -h localhost -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDb.* TO tmpUser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'tmpPass'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
// truncate all tables except table1 and table2
mysql -u tmpUser -ptmpPass -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, '; ') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'testDb' AND table_name NOT IN ('table1', 'table2');"
```

And the out put in terminal is

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, '; ')                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE TABLE tableX;                                                |
| TRUNCATE TABLE tableY;                                                |
| TRUNCATE TABLE tableZ;                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which is OK, because based on log all tables got TRUNCATED except table1 and table2, but the problem is that when I check in database if tables are truncated, data is still present. So if I check tableX, tableY or tableZ it still has records in it.

So the question is: Is there something wrong with my TRUNCATE TABLES command? Can I somehow check if there is some mysql process which is not finished maybe. How to debug this?
I'm working on Vagrant machine (just telling if this could be a case in any way).

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem with some sort shell script... It goes like this

```
EXCLUDETABLES=('table1' 'table2')
ALLTABLES=$(mysql -u root -ppass -Nse "SHOW TABLES testDb")
for TABLE in $ALLTABLES
do
    DOTRUNCATE="yes"
    for EX in "${EXCLUDETABLES[@]}"
    do
        if [[ "$EX" == "$TABLE" ]]; then
            DOTRUNCATE="no"
            break
        fi
    done
    
    if [[ "$DOTRUNCATE" == "yes" ]]; then
        mysql -u root -ppass -e "TRUNCATE TABLE testDb.$TABLE;"
    fi
done
```